# simplifying $ (h^2_2-h^2_3)\over ({1\over h_3})-({1\over h_2})$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Can someone please show me how these are equivalent in steps $\frac{(h_2^2 - h_3^2 )}{\dfrac{1}{h_3}-\dfrac{1}{h_2}}=h_2 h_3 (h_2+h_3)$ I thought it simplifies to $$(h_2^2-h_3^2)(h_3-h_2)$$This would be much appreciated, I cant wrap my head around it.

Comment: oo ok will do thanks

Answer (score 2):

Well, to start with, note that $$\frac1{h_3}-\frac1{h_2}=\frac{h_2}{h_2h_3}-\frac{h_3}{h_2h_3}=\frac{h_2-h_3}{h_2h_3}.$$ Can you take it from there?

If your reasoning were correct, then, for example, letting $h_2=2$ and $h_3=1,$ we would have $$6=\frac{3}{1/2}=\cfrac{2^2-1^2}{\frac11-\frac12}=(2^2-1^2)(1-2)=-3,$$ which of course is not true.

Answer (score 0):

Expand by $h_2h_3$ and note that $h_2^2-h_3^2=(h_2-h_3)(h_2+h_3)$.